# Game Maker: is 08 the same as 8 in arrays?

Tags: game-maker

if I make an array `A_[01]`, can I refer to it later with `A_[1]`?

I am asking because I am not sure if this is the reason why I am getting some bugs.

Comment: I never used game maker, but in many programming languages, prefixing a number with a 0 means it's in [octal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Comment: Actually a valid question, some languages could treat such statement as hashmap with string keys... in which case there would be difference.

Comment: Yes, it's same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say confidently without testing myself, you should test yourself (see the bold below). However, reading [the documentation on Data Types](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/data%20types.html) the following line is stated:

> real numbers are any value that is not a string, nor any of the other possible data types.

The documentation makes no mention of octal literals, which is where 0 might be a prefix, and it doesn't make any mention of binary literal values.
[This documentation page](http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/drawing/color%20and%20blending/index.html) mentions the only hexadecimal format relates to the `$` character which is used for color values.

> Note that you can also create colours from their hexadecimal value using the "$" symbol beforehand

Finally, [this page on the arrays](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/001_gml%20language%20overview/401_06_arrays.html) and their indexing has no mention of any special array indexing meaning. The data types like map appear to use functions rather than syntax to access the keys so I don't expect this to be an implicit map.

This leads me to conclude that if the GML parser reads a prefixed `0` as a real number, `02` should be equivalent to `2`. **You can test this theory by printing the result of `02 == 2`**, or put `02` into a variable and print the value, if it prints out as `2` it might be parsed as a real number. *Note that I use 2 instead of 1 because if there is a binary literal somehow it won't translate.*

I'd suggest you avoid relying on side effects (I'd consider this a side effect of the first quoted line) and be explicit: use the integer literal without the prefix to be sure and future proof.